# How to retrieve the history url in javascript

Tags: javascript

Background:

I'm trying to update a website, and there is a `Login.html` page which will be redirected to when login is required.

But now the customer want to make the login page to slide from bottom (not redirect to).

I'm trying to make it with least effort. So I'm trying to let the original `Login.html` goes back always, and then on every page, detect whether the `history.forward()` page is the original `Login.html`, if yes, slide the new login page after loaded.

---

But it leads to a technical question, how to fetch the `history.forward` url only but don't go to that page? I've found the solution but not found.

Any good suggestion to my background target would also be appreciated.

---

Thanks to the comment, I already know that doing this on history is not allowed. But what if I store the visit stack on `localStorage`? And now the question reduced to how to distinguish different window? I want to store the visit stack according to the key of different window.

Comment: Use document.referer for previous page and see here for explanation on why you can't get URL's for security reasons in javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript

Comment: @Onimusha Don't assume `referer` will always work, some people disable it to improve privacy.

Comment: ok, thank you @Onimusha, but I was only want the functional, so alternative solution on my site might work, for example, what about using localStorage to remember the visited page stack?

Comment: Looks like you need your own history stack refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846248/how-to-implement-my-own-history-stack-in-a-single-page-mobile-web-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several effort, I found using the `history.go` method cannot lead to the solution.

But this purpose, we can maintain the visit stack on localStorage or cookie.